# How to call a function/procedure in an SQL where clause?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, where-clause

I've been stuck for the last little while trying to call a function in my sql query. Ideally I would like to do the following:

```
from c in db.items
where calcDistance(c.Latitude, c.Longitude, Latitude, Longitude) =< radius
select ...
```

However, as far as I know, I can't call a local c# function inside a where clause. I did a bit of research and tried to create a stored procedure to call a user defined function which does the equivalent such as the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DistanceProc
    @lat1 decimal,
    @long1 decimal,
    @lat2 decimal,
    @long2 decimal
AS
    DECLARE @return FLOAT
    SET @return = dbo.Distance(@lat1, @long1, @lat2, @long2)
SELECT @return
```

where dbo.Distance is my user defined function with the same logic as my original c# function. Then I tried to add a function import, but with no scalar type FLOAT, I tried to return a double. Then tried to use this code:

```
from c in db.items
where radius >=  db.DistanceProc(c.Latitude, c.Longitude, Latitude, Longitude)
select ...
```

However, db.DistanceProc() returns a type of System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<double?> and not just a normal double. I tried to add a .Cast<double>().FirstOrDefault() to this, but then it can't translate to a store expression.

At this point, I'm pretty much stuck on ideas. Is there a simple way to achieve this? All I need is to perform this extra distance calculation logic within the where clause for each item in the DB. I was also looking at just returning the all the items in an IEnumerable and then running the logic on it after locally, but as the DB is rather large, it isn't feasible to return every item.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've also tried just calling the UDF instead of the stored procedure using [these instructions on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847%28VS.100%29.aspx), but it still doesn't work. It compiles fine, but at runtime it throws a NotSupportedException with the following message:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double] Distance(System.Decimal, System.Decimal, System.Decimal, System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the sql function in your where clause, you cannot call the stored procedure.

```
from c in db.items
where radius >=  db.Distance(c.Latitude, c.Longitude, Latitude, Longitude) -- CALL function instead of procedure
```

Comment: My c# class doesn't seem to have reference to the function, and when I try to import the function, it doesn't show up in the drop down of selections. Is there some additional work I need to do to get the udf to show up?

Comment: I tried to read up a bit more on your approach, and I tried one way (see EDIT in original post), however the only difference is I had to call it directly and not prefixed with the "db.", as it is still undefined under that context because I wasn't able to create a functionimport. When I tried, it complained that functionimports cannot have a scalar return type.